# Weird situation when returning char *

Tags: c

I am pretty new to C programming and I have several functions returning type `char *`

Say I declare `char a[some_int];`, and I fill it later on. When I attempt to return it at the end of the function, it will only return the `char` at the first index. One thing I noticed, however, is that it will return the entirety of `a` if I call any sort of function on it prior to returning it. For example, my function to check the size of a string (calling something along the lines of `strLength(a);`).

I'm very curious what the situation is with this exactly. Again, I'm new to C programming (as you probably can tell).

EDIT: Additionally, if you have any advice concerning the best method of returning this, please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT 2: For example:

I have `char ret[my_strlen(a) + my_strlen(b)];` in which a and b are strings and my_strlen returns their length.

Then I loop through filling `ret` using `ret[i] = a[i];` and incrementing.

When I call my function that prints an input string (as a test), it prints out how I want it, but when I do

`return ret;`

or even

```
char *ptr = ret;
return ptr;
```

it never supplies me with the full string, just the first char.

Comment: This question will go much better if you post your code instead of trying to describe your code

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to return local variables. Variables declared inside `{ }` stop existing when execution leaves that block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way not working to return a chunk of char data is to return it in memory temporaryly allocated on the **stack** during the execution of your function and (most probably) already used for another purpose after it returned.

A working alternative would be to allocate the chunk of memory ont the **heap**. Make sure you read up about and understand the difference between stack and heap memory! The `malloc()` family of functions is your friend if you choose to return your data in a chunk of memory allocated on the heap (see `man malloc`).

`char* a = (char*) malloc(some_int * sizeof(char))` should help in your case. Make sure you don't forget to free up memory once you don't need it any more.
`char* ret = (char*) malloc((my_strlen(a) + my_strlen(b)) * sizeof(char))` for the second example given. Again don't forget to free once the memory isn't used any more.

As **MByD** correctly pointed out, it is not forbidden in general to use memory allocated on the **stack** to pass chunks of data in and out of functions. As long as the chunk is not allocated on the stack of the function returning this is also quite well.

In the scenario below function `b` will work on a chunk of memory allocated on the stackframe created, when function `a` entered and living until `a` returns. So everything will be pretty fine even though no memory allocated on the heap is involved.

```
void b(char input[]){
 /* do something useful here */
}

void a(){
  char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
  b(buf)
  /* use data filled in by b here */
}
```

As still another option you may choose to leave memory allocation on the heap to the compiler, using a global variable. I'd count at least this option to the last resort category, as not handled properly, global variables are the main culprits in raising problems with reentrancy and multithreaded applications.

Happy hacking and good luck on your learning C mission.

Comment: This is not the best and absolutely not the only way to return chunk of data. In many cases output buffer will be more convenient, and in some cases you don't have a heap at all. (other options, btw, is to return a structure with an array inside or to have a global variable for the buffer, I don't think they are better, but they DO exist)

Comment: ... which in turn all are memory areas living on the heap. Thus exactly what I was trying to say.

Comment: nope, output buffer maybe on the stack as well (such as when using `sscanf` to read a string), also, global variables does not live in the heap.

Comment: Ooooh, I see what you are pointing it. How right your are. Preallocated by the linker I'd count globals to heap memory, but only returning a reference to your own stack is real trouble. I'll try to fix in the answer.